# Laggy Youtube performance

Tags: gnome, firefox, video, chromium, youtube

Youtube works fine in Windows, but in Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 video is very not smooth. Framerate drops, the lag is very visible when things move on the screen.

- both Firefox and Chromium have this issue, although the latter is slightly better;
- Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 booted from a USB stick acted the same way;
- I have an AMD video card;
- I tried both the open and fglrx drivers;
- I have "Resticted extras" installed;
- Youtube itself says my browser supports everything;
- Vlc plays these vids very nice and smoothly.

Comment: Are you using the flash plugin or html5 player?

Comment: As far as I can understand, it's HTML5.

Answer (score 4):

To fix this I went to Firefox **about:config** menu and set **layers.acceleration.force-enabled** to **true**.

Comment: It's weird, I got the problem in a way  that there is wave in youtube video when the scence is fast (like action), I change the value you metion to false and it's better.